# For Loop Ignores True IF Condition When ELSE Is Present

Tags: excel, vb.net, if-statement, for-loop

It would appear that I have an issue with getting my For Loop to acknowledge I have a `True` `IF` condition, when an `ELSE` condition exists in the loop body. Here's what I've written:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'TEST FIND/SEARCH FEATURES
    Dim String2Find As String = txtCPUSerial.Text
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer = 1

    'Access the worksheet
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Machine\Desktop\DocDirectory\MyDoc.xls") 

    Dim xWS As Excel.Worksheet

    xWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'TRY TO LOOP THROUGH THE ROWS..

     For x As Integer = 1 To xWS.Rows.Count Step 1

        'Check if cell value matches the search string...
        If xWS.Cells(x, ColumnNumber).value = String2Find Then
            MessageBox.Show("Got it..." & String2Find & " in row " & x)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Item not in the sheet...")

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I've tried writing a straight statement in my `Else` where the `String2Find <> txtCPUSerial.Text`, but either the syntax blows up, or I'm still getting the message dialog for **"Item not in the sheet..."**, thus the True portion of my For Loop gets ignored while stepping through, and won't return dialog upon getting a `True` condition.

If I remove my `Else`, then obviously the code loops accordingly and will return the text, if the textbox value does exists in my sheet (I've written an arbitrary value in the sheet to find. What am I not including or specifying that's causing this to occur?

Comment: define `syntax blows up`  You are comparing `Object` to string, so there is that

Comment: When stepping over the procedure, what is the value of `String2Find` in the `IF statement`? Is it getting the `txtCPUSerial.Text` correctly?

Comment: Think about what your code does the first time round the `For` loop. If the string isn't found you will execute the `Else` block of the `If` statement which exits the `For` loop (`Exit For`).

Comment: @BranislavKollár Yes, it is. Interestingly, mentioning what Blackwood has said, when the code does find the string the first time around, it is still ignoring it, and thus running the Else condition. I've tried placing a Exit For  before Else to break out if the condition is true, but it still gets ignored.

Comment: @Plutonix What I'm mean is that the syntax is incorrect when trying to say something like the following: `(txtCPUSerial.Text <> String2Find) ` in the Else statement. I get syntax error.

Comment: About the syntax error, you cannot explicitly specify the condition in `Else`, use `Elseif CONDITION` instead. I have one more question. What is the purpose of the macro? Find all of occurences, or find the first, if exists? Or what?

Comment: @BranislavKollár I've tried doing on that within an `ElseIf` as well, and my `True` condition is still ignored. The purpose of this is if there is an existing value in a spreadsheet, for it to be detected. If my code works for at least properly identifying that a value typed into the textbox actually exists in the spreadsheet, then the next goal will be to edit that value, or leave it be. Hence, all detected occurrences will be sought.

Answer (score 1):

Seems easier to show you sample on how to find it than to explain all the issues in your code:

```
Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application  ' this starts new Excel Application
Dim xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Machine\Desktop\DocDirectory\MyDoc.xls") 
Dim xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Dim xlColA = xlWS.Range("A:A")       ' Column A
Dim xlCell = xlColA.Find(txtCPUSerial.Text) ' or .Find(txtCPUSerial.Text,,,XlLookAt.xlWhole)

If xlCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox(txtCPUSerial.Text & " not found")
Else 
    MsgBox(txtCPUSerial.Text & " found on row " & xlCell.Row)
End If

' don't forget to close the Workbook and Excel Application
xlWB.Close() 
xlApp.Quit()
```

[How to: Programmatically Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a)

Comment: This seems to work well, granted some rearranging, but when I try to use it with `Replace`, I'm getting hung up on Excel telling me it can't find anything to replace. Yet the item I'm searching for through the `textbox` comes up. I had `xlwB.Save(), xlWB.Close(), xlApp.Quit()` already, followed by some release statements. Something is still locking up my sheet like it's protected now.

Comment: Range.Find and Range.Replace have parameter to search the whole cell or part, so you can try that or wildcards like `.Replace("*" & txtCPUSerial.Text & "*")`. It is usually easier to use the Record Macro in Excel to generate the code and then you can use it with some small adjustments.

Comment: So looking at your example, and a few others, I was able to work up something. However, I notice that there's no equivalent for the Match Entire Cell Contents option in the Excel Find function. `MatchCase:=` seems to be available, and when trying to use something like `MatchEntireCellContents:=` it returned an error. Is there a way to add this in...? Or will I write logic that specifically disallows returning a `substring` of the value in the textbox?

Comment: it's the `Lookat:=XlLookAt.xlWhole`

Comment: I already have this, in fact, using it like this: `LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.XlWhole`. I'm still able to retrieve part of a given string. If you try on a value, you'll see what I mean. Even in Excel, there's the Match Entire Cell Contents checkbox.  I don't believe there's `VB.Net` way of acheiving this without strictly declaring not to bring back a substring.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the code is to **find all occurences and replace** them with something else, I suggest using **Find and Replace method**.

Sample code, tested and working:

```
Sub FindAndReplace()
    Dim FoundCell As Range

    With Columns("A:A")
        Set FoundCell = .Find(What:="old", After:=.Cells(1), _
        LookIn:=-4163, LookAt:=1, SearchOrder:=1, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=True, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Item not in the sheet...")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            .Replace What:="old", Replacement:="new", LookAt:=1, _
                SearchOrder:=1, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

What it does:

1. The find method returns a `Range object` of the found cell or `Nothing` in case it didn't find anything. Stores the result in the `FoundCell` variable.
2. It checks if the `FoundCell` variable is `Nothing`
3. If it is nothing, it displays the message and exits sub.
4. If it is not nothing (meaning it found a match), it uses replace method to change all the "old" values to the "new" ones.

Comment: This looks good, but this isn't recognized by VB.Net: I get code errors on `xlWhole, xlValues, xlNext` and the like. Pretty much all of the `xl` items.

Comment: Hi. Those are excel enumerations. I have replaced them with integer eqivalents. You can find more about Find Method on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx